# How to create scala recursive method

Tags: scala, methods

I am trying to help a recursive method in scala that removes a particular number from a list and returns that list without the given number.
I can only use if/else statements and pairing (::)

So far I have this but I am not sure how to remove items from a list in scala.

```
def removeNum(lst: List[Int]): lst2:List[Int] = lst match { 
var lst2:Int
case Nil =>0
case h::t=>{ 
  if(h !=0)
      lst2(h)// how do I iterate thru the list without using foreach?    
   }
else {
   removeNum(rest)
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a better approach to this method.

Comment: A better approach is to use the standard library's `filter` method on lists: `lst.filter(x => x != numberToRemove)`

Comment: I can't use the library. I am not looking for the whole code, just a way to accomplish this task of removing a number, using only helper methods, patterns, and if/else

Comment: Which parameter is the "given number" that you are trying to remove?

Comment: Why can't you use the library? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I don't have that because I am trying to add the number (in this case a 0) to another list.

Comment: @Eduardo It seems like a safe assumption that this is homework...or at least a learning exercise.

Comment: Yes. It's a learning excercise

Comment: @Varoag You don't have what? Do you mean that you don't have a variable with the number you are trying to remove? Now that's awfully confusing since your question states that you want to write a method that removes a given number from a list. This makes it sound like you need two parameters rather than just one.

Comment: I like your response @Code-Apprentice. My train of thought was to remove, but since I was having issues with removing something, I thought I could create another list w/out the unwanted number and return that. But your method of thinking makes much more sense

Comment: I just saw the edit. Thx! I get it now.

Comment: Also I don't think `def removeNum(lst: List[Int]): lst2:List[Int] = `... will compile since you cannot declare the variable `lst2` at this location in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The basic approach is to compare the "given number" against the head of the list. If there is a match, return the recursive result on only the rest of the list. Otherwise, return a list created by keeping the head of the list and recursing on the rest of the list. Notice that it is easier to think about whether or not to **keep** the head of the list rather than thinking about **removing** elements from the list.

Note that this requires a second parameter: the "given number" which you want to remove.

Answer (score -3):

While I think you should use filter, you could use:

```
def removeNum(xs: List[Int], toRemove: Int): List[Int] = xs match {
  case x :: xss => if (x == toRemove)
    removeNum(xss, toRemove)
  else
    x :: removeNum(xss, toRemove)
  case List() => List()
}
```

Comment: The OP asked explicitly not to give all the code. Also, your version has a subtle bug that will not give the correct result in some instances.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: while this answer spoils the learning experience, I do not see an explicit request not to give the code away.

Comment: @Eduardo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998711/how-to-create-scala-recursive-method/34998869?noredirect=1#comment57725555_34998711

Comment: @Eduardo Besides, the more important thing is that this answer isn't completely correct.

Comment: More than one bug, actually.

Comment: I've updated the answer to at least remove the bugs. I didn't notice that the OP didn't want a code answer. My apologies for that